# display the UpdateView form on the same page as CreateView form in django

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I want to display the UpdateView form on the same page as CreateView form so whenever "Edit" button is clicked the UpdateView form is displayed on the same page

```
<button type="button" class="edit_btn" data-url="{% url 'parts:stock_update_view' stock.id %}">Edit</button>
```

ajax for edit button:

```
         $.ajax({
             url: $(this).data('url'),
             data: {            
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
             alert(data.name);
             }
         });
     }
  });
class stock_update_view(UpdateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(stock_update_view, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['update_form'] = context.get('form')
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.GET.get('username', None)
        data = {

        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

I want to get back the UpdateView form as jsonResponse so that I can render it in my template.after returning context['update_form'] = context.get('form') will I be able to render the pre-filled form in my template if yes then how can I  return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define get_initial() function like this:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = {
                'part_id' : self.request.user.part_id
                'entry_date: self.....
              }
    return initial
```

This function will pre-populate the form which you are passing in the context.